# Are there equal numbers of male and female Christians?

Tags: global-christianity, gender, demographics

I've heard it suggested the male/female ratio of Christians is such that there are significantly more female Christians than male Christians.

Is this true? I don't seem to be able to find an answer online, but presumably statistics must exist, e.g. census or church registers (although of course there are potentially biases within such records).

Comment: (I don't see why this would be considered 'opinion-based', I'm looking specifically for some sort of statistics, rather than opinion.)

Comment: How would you determine whether or not someone is a Christian?  There would be a million different ways to calculate this.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is almost certainly "no" for any reasonable way of determining who is a Christian. The probability of two such large numbers being exactly equal is extremely small.

Comment: I think the question is fine. There are demographic numbers available on things like this. I'm sure an estimation based on those would be acceptable to the asker. @AndreasBlass I am equally certain that the asker means "about equal." Differing by 3% is probably "equal" in most people's mind.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics likely to change over time and unlikely to be helpful to future visitors 

Comment: What if we changed it to where have there been survey reports of a substantial gender imbalance? But that's a little list-y...

Comment: Or if we just live it alone as is, for reasons I listed above ...

Comment: This is essentially a statistics question. One would have to record ratios of males to females in 15,379 randomly selected churches to obtain an estimate within 1% margin of error (and with 99% confidence).

Answer (score 5):

Here is some ad-hoc information about the church in the US:

http://churchformen.com/men-and-church/where-are-the-men/

According to these numbers, and if we assume Christian activity is a reasonable estimate of the probability of being a Christian, then there are more Christian women than men and the difference is probably quite significant.

The author's summary/opinion:

> You’re not just imagining it. Christianity is short on men.

His statistics are based primarily on church attendance:

> The typical U.S. Congregation draws an adult crowd that’s 61% female, 39% male. >This gender gap shows up in all age categories.
>
> On any given Sunday there are 13 million more adult women than men in America’s >churches.
>
> This Sunday almost 25 percent of married, churchgoing women will worship without >their husbands.
>
> Midweek activities often draw 70 to 80 percent female participants.

Some countries may have an even greater imbalance:

> Churches overseas report gender gaps of up to 9 women for every adult man in attendance.

Belief versus commitment:

> More than 90 percent of American men believe in God, and five out of six call themselves Christians. But only one out of six attend church on a given Sunday. The average man accepts the reality of Jesus Christ, but fails to see any value in going to church.

The significance of that depends on your definition of "Christian". This strongly suggests that there are a lot more active female Christians than active male Christians.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. If you're interested in _why_, I recommend reading _Wild at Heart_ by John Eldgridge

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest it's impossible to know how many Christians there are in the world.

Slightly easier would be the number of people claiming to be Christian - a look at Census data in a lot of countries will tell you this information. The Australian Bureau of Statistics suggests that more percentage wise more women than men claim to be Christians (http://www.abs.gov.au/Ausstats/abs@.nsf/0/FA58E975C470B73CCA256E9E00296645?opendocument). Whether these people actual are Christians and whether they are practicing Christians (attend church, read their bible, live in a "Christian" way) is unknown.

Although I'm not sure if it is reflected globally, there is an organisation called NCLS that runs surveys in churches in Australia (and possibly around the world). There numbers show that men represent 39% of church attendees (http://www.ncls.org.au/default.aspx?sitemapid=137). You could rightly argue that not everyone attending church is a Christian but that brings me back to my first point that it's impossible to know how many Christians there are in the world.

Comment: From the ncls page: "Only 39% of attenders are male" and "In every denomination, in every age grouping, women outnumber men."